# PowerShell using SQL Server SMO with Split-Path

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm new so maybe this is just something I need explained.

When working with PoSH with SQL Server SMO I'd like to get the path for tempdb. I have written the code to pull the data I want, but the results are not what I expect.

It returns:

@{FileName=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA

What I was expecting:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA

Can someone educate me please?

Example: (SMO will need to be loaded already)

```
$ServerName = 'LOCALHOST' #testing code
$server = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $ServerName
$server.Databases.FileGroups.Files | where-object {$_.Name -eq 'tempdev'} | select FileName | Split-Path -Parent
```

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change that last line to:

```
($server.Databases.FileGroups.Files | 
   where-object {$_.Name -eq 'tempdev'}).Filename | 
   split-path -Parent;
```

A simple explanation is that the way you've written it, the `select FileName` is still returning a DataFile object (albeit one that has only the Filename property). By wrapping the part where you get the file in parens and then calling `.FileName` on that, you're getting a string back. Which split-path is a little happier about.

Comment: Great feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to try either:

```
$server.Databases.FileGroups.Files | 
    where-object {$_.Name -eq 'tempdev'} | 
    select -ExpandProperty FileName | 
    Split-Path -Parent
```

Or:

```
$server.Databases.FileGroups.Files | 
    where-object {$_.Name -eq 'tempdev'} | 
    ForEach-Object FileName | 
    Split-Path -Parent
```

The basic problem is that you've misunderstood what `Select-Object` is doing.  It returns *an object with the properties you specify*, not the property itself.

See if this helps.  Here's `Select-Object` with one property:

```
PS C:\> $x = gci C:\Windows\notepad.exe | Select FullName
PS C:\> $x

FullName
--------
C:\Windows\notepad.exe


PS C:\> $x.FullName
C:\Windows\notepad.exe
PS C:\> $x.GetType().Name
PSCustomObject
```

And here we see it behaves the same with multiple properties:

```
PS C:\> $x = gci C:\Windows\notepad.exe | Select FullName, Length
PS C:\> $x

FullName               Length
--------               ------
C:\Windows\notepad.exe 244736


PS C:\> $x.FullName
C:\Windows\notepad.exe
PS C:\> $x.GetType().Name
PSCustomObject
```

And here it is again with the `-ExpandProperty` parameter.

```
PS C:\> $x = gci C:\Windows\notepad.exe | Select -ExpandProperty FullName
PS C:\> $x
C:\Windows\notepad.exe
PS C:\> $x.GetType().Name
String
PS C:\> $x.FullName
PS C:\>
```

You should be able to replace `| Select -ExpandProperty FullName` with `| ForEach-Object FullName` and see the same behavior.  Note that you can only specify one parameter with either of these methods.

Comment: Great feedback. Thank you.

Comment: I always forget about `-ExpandProperty`!